# Произвольный файл добавить в ресурсную часть скопимилированной dll

Tags: c#, dll

Доброго времени суток!

Знаю что можно, был пример написанный (исходников нет) на дельфи.

Введение:

- Есть dll, суть которой просто хранилище разных всяких ресурсов (начиная от картинок и текста, до внешних представлений всяческих окошек)...
- Есть произвольный файл (ну скажем будет он txt формата.

Задача:

- Поместить в ресурсную часть известной dll известный файл с именем ресурса соответствующему имени файла.

На 90% уверен, что это можно сделать при помощи WinAPI и на 60% уверен, что это можно сделать средствами c# через Reflection... Но хоть убейте, все глаза просмотрел, ничего не могу найти.

PS: dll создана средствами c# (думаю это важно)... для разнообразия, будет полезно знать, если dll будет создана не для framework

Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два вида ресурсов: нативные ресурсы, и ресурсы .NET.

Для работы с нативными ресурсами вы можете использовать [эту библиотеку](http://resourcelib.codeplex.com/) или [это готовое решение](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20644/Command-line-tool-with-source-code-to-add-native-r). Может быть, вам пригодится майкрософтовская [mt.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Попробуйте!

Заметьте, что модификация файла (даже добавление ресурсов) нарушит цифровую подпись, поэтому если ваша DLL имеет [strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), оно отвалится.

Для того, чтобы изменить ресурсы .NET, лучше всего просто держать исходник библиотеки и перекомпилировать его с командной строки. Компилятор C# -- часть установки .NET, так что он будет на всех клиентских системах.

Вы не сможете ничего сделать при помощи Reflection, так как Reflection в любом случае может поменять лишь данные *в памяти*, но не *на диске*.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Т.е. библиотеки c# не могут изменяться? требуется всегда полная перекомпиляция?.. а если это нужно сделать на стороне пользователя, не имея исходных кодов?..

Почитаю про компиляцию через командную строку проектов c#, никогда этого не требовалось =) F6 в студии и понеслось =)

Comment: @pincher1519: может быть и могут, но я не знаю способа. На стороне пользователя можно и держать исходный код, он для библиотеки-контейнера ресурсов всё равно будет пустой (или почти пустой).

Comment: @pincher1519: Если компиляция нативных библиотек на стороне клиента -- проблема (скорее всего, у клиента нету компилятора), то с .net-библиотеками проще. Поскольку у клиента есть .NET framework, есть и компилятор (он часть поставки .NET).